# on dom ready append html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have legacy database with holds beside rest html source which is used by a client to render some page snippets. I want to fetch all images inside `#mainNewsBody .news p` and to add link to that image `rel='superbox[image]'`

Now it's

`<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/DSCF1087.JPG" />` and it should be

`<img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/DSCF1087.JPG" rel='superbox[image]'/>`

how can I achive this using jquery on dom ready?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
 $('#mainNewsBody .news img').attr('rel', 'superbox[image]');
});
```

Comment: I am a little slow in typing.. +1 for typing faster .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mainNewsBody .news p img').attr("rel", "superbox[image]");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mainNewsBody .news p img').attr('rel', 'superbox[image]');
});
```